# Using CASE statements in ORDER BY

Tags: sql-order-by, case, postgresql-9.2

I have a query that needs to take a different order, based other fields. It is possible to use a `CASE` statement in an `ORDER BY`, so so far that is working fine. The only thing that doesn't seem possible, is to change the ascending/descending part.

My query:

```
SELECT articleid, MIN(createtime) min,  MAX(createtime) max
FROM items 
GROUP BY articleid
ORDER BY
       CASE WHEN logic='foo' THEN min ELSE '0001-01-01 00:00:00' END ASC,
       CASE WHEN logic='bar' THEN max ELSE '0001-01-01 00:00:00' END DESC;
```

works, but I was wondering if a form like this could be made (I know this doesn't work):

```
SELECT articleid, MIN(createtime) min,  MAX(createtime) max
FROM items 
GROUP BY articleid
ORDER BY
       CASE WHEN logic='foo' THEN min ASC ELSE max DESC END;
```

Comment: You can't have the `ASC` and `DESC` inside the case. It only applies to the whole expression on which you are sorting.

Answer (score 0):

The `ASC` and `DESC` are only allowed at the end of the expressions. However, you could put the `ASC` at then end and just negate the max in the ELSE clause (assuming there's no nulls complicating the matter).

```
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN logic='foo' THEN min ELSE -max END ASC;
```